# Problema con Labels en Jupiternotebook

Tags: python, jupyter, machine-learning

como va? tengo un problema con el codigo en jupyter notebook, cargo todas las librerias, y no me reconoce el labels de la muestra que estoy analizando. Usando el algoritmo de Bayes. Tengo cargado esto:
[image: Librerias que utilizo]

Y me aparece este error... [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero al sacar los labels se me va.
Los labels los necesito para hacer los modelos de Bayes, ya que es una poblacion completamente desbalanceada. Donde un 7% compra un producto y el otro 93% no

Answer (score 0):

**NameError** ocurre cuando Python no puede reconocer el identificador al que hace referencia, probablemente porque no fue definido previamente. El comando mágico `whom` (Jupyter) le proporcionará una lista ordenada de todas las variables del contexto actual:

```
In [1]: LABELS = ['x', 'y', 'z']
In [3]: whos
Variable   Type    Data/Info
----------------------------
LABELS     list    n=3
```

Si el identificador no se encuentra en la lista, pruebe a ejecutar cualquier celda que asigne un valor a `LABELS`.

Comment: Gracias, he avanzado bastante y me tope con un nuevo problema: f = msb / msw